# Laravel, Undefined Variable in Views

Tags: laravel-5, undefined

I tried to work on my problem but i'm stuck here can't resolve why the variable is undefined in **home.blade.php** 
This is my HomeController.php where i have **$items** variable which is causing problem

```
<?php
 use app\Item;
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

class HomeController extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct(Item $items)
    {
        $this->items = $items;
    }

    public function getIndex()
    {
        $items = Auth::user()->items;

        return View::make('home', array(
        'items' => $items    
        ));
    }



    public function postIndex()
    {
        $id = Input::get('id');
        $useId = Auth::user()->id;

        $item = Item::findOrFail($id);

        if($item->owner_id == $userId)
        $item -> mark();

        return Redirect::route('home');
    }
}
?>
```

and this is Items class where i have extended it with eloquent

```
<?php
class Item extends Eloquent
{
    public function mark()
    {
        $this->done = $this->done?false:true;
        $this->save();
    }
}
```

while i have another function of **items** which i'm trying to use as a variable in view this is file of **user.php** and function is defined at the end

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract,
                                    AuthorizableContract,
                                    CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];

    public function items()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Item','owner_id');
    }
}
```

And this is the file from views **home.blade.php** where its giving error on foreach loop
 
**Error: ErrorException in b5a9f5fc2ee329af8de0b5c94fd30f78 line 7:
Undefined variable: items (View: C:\Users\Rehman_\Desktop\todo-application\resources\views\home.blade.php)**

```
@extends('master')

@section('content')

    <h1>TO DO: Items</h1>
    <hr>

    <ul>
        @foreach ($items as $item)
        @endforeach
    </ul>

@stop
```

Update: **Route.php** file

```
<?php

Route::get('/',array('as'=>'home','uses'=>'PageController@getindex'))->before('auth');

Route::post('/',array('uses','HomeController@postIndex'))->before('csrf');

Route::get('/login',array('as'=>'login','uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin'))->before('guest');

Route::post('login',array('uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin'))->before('csrf');
```

Comment: In HomeController you could try `return view('home',compact('items'))`

Comment: i have already tried that @IE5Master :( i have even tried with view('home')->with('item',$item) but didn't help

Comment: everything seems fine. Are you sure your route is pointing to the correct controller and its method?

Comment: @Digitlimit i have updated the code with the route.php file can you have a look please ?

Comment: The issue is this Route::get('/',array('as'=>'home','uses'=>'PageController@getindex'))->before('auth'); its not pointing to home controller where the variable is set

Comment: Try Route::get('/', ['middleware'=>'auth', 'as'=>'home','uses'=>'HomeController@getIndex'] );

Comment: in your controller you have get**I**ndex but in the routes you have get**i**ndex

Comment: @IE5Master 
yea thanks for indicating that i have corrected the I there, but it didn't affect the home file. how ever it has generated a new error **undefined variable**

Comment: with this code of route i have i changed the controller        
`Route::get('/',array('as'=>'home','uses'=>'HomeController@getIndex'))->before('auth');

 Route::get('/login',array('as'=>'login','uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin'))->before('guest');

Route::post('login',array('uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin'))->before('csrf');
` and the error shifts to
`Class App\Http\Controllers\Item does not exist` still don't know whether the error of variable is resolved or not

Comment: did you include the Item namespace in your HomeController? Is there a column in your user table called items?

Comment: yes i have included **app\Item**, should i run **composer dump-autoload** ?

Comment: I cannot see items as variable in postIndex method in controller, Is there something I'm missing??

Comment: @stackMonk yes i have used it surely in **HomeController** code :(

Comment: @HabibRehman In your post it does not look like you have included the Item namespace `use App\Item;` or something of the sort inside of HomeController.

Comment: @IE5Master sorry i forgot to update the question i had it in my file. And one thing more here the Route::method should be POST. if i make Route::GET the error changes to **Class App\Http\Controllers\Item does not exist**

Comment: @HabibRehman go to file : vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php and search if "App\Http\Controllers\Item" is mapped to right item you are referring to..

Comment: @stackMonk coldn't even find app\http\controller\item in the autoload_classmap.php file

Comment: @HabibRehman search for any class 'item' in that file

Comment: @stackMonk there is just information of database related to Item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
return View('home', compact('items'));
```

Instead of this:

```
return View::make('home', array(
    'items' => $items    
));
```

Comment: i have already tried this bro, however with the help of other guys i have changed the controller by changing it now says **Class App\Http\Controllers\Item does not exist**, now i guess it doesn't even find a class.

Comment: Did you add `Item` at the top of your controller? Ex: `use App\Item;`

Comment: after changing the name you will have to "composer dump-autoload", it will update the autoload_classmap.php file in vendor/composer with your new class name.

Comment: @smartrahat yes i have used it, now running composer dump

Answer (score 1):

Your route is probably pointing to the wrong controller/method hence the variable is not been sent to the view.

Try:

```
 Route::get('/', [ 'as'=>'home','uses'=>'HomeController@getIndex'] );
```

Comment: why do we have to use **'middleware'=>'auth'** here ? its sending me to **localhost:8000/auth/login**

Comment: Added it based on your code,. Have removed it. If you must use Auth::user()->items then you need to include it

Comment: Which URL is your request going to

Comment: when i use your method and run **localhost:8000** it automatically re directs me to **localhost:8000/auth/login**

Comment: Remove the middleware see my updated answer. Hope you know what you are doing. I can see you are using $items = Auth::user()->items; 
Which means only authenticated user can get related lists

Comment: okay i have done this, also the method should be post(), right? And the problem persists

Comment: Why post? Not post since you are returning a view